# How to show residual in the bottom of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to reproduce this plot. The errors are shown in the bottom of the plot. Can you please share how its done?
[image]

There is an example that I found here on stackoverflow, but it is in R. 
[How to create a graph showing the predictive model, data and residuals in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699236/how-to-create-a-graph-showing-the-predictive-model-data-and-residuals-in-r)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371198/residual-plot-not-aligned-with-main-graph This thread gives solution.

Answer (score 15):

You can create such plot in Matplotlib only by using [add_axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes). Here is an example.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
#Data
x = arange(1,10,0.2)
ynoise = x*numpy.random.rand(len(x)) 
#Noise; noise is scaled by x, in order to it be noticable on a x-squared function
ydata = x**2 + ynoise #Noisy data

#Model
Fofx = lambda x,a,b,c: a*x**2+b*x+c
#Best fit parameters
p, cov = curve_fit(Fofx,x,ydata)

#PLOT
fig1 = figure(1)
#Plot Data-model
frame1=fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.8,.6))
#xstart, ystart, xend, yend [units are fraction of the image frame, from bottom left corner]
plot(x,ydata,'.b') #Noisy data
plot(x,Fofx(x,*p),'-r') #Best fit model
frame1.set_xticklabels([]) #Remove x-tic labels for the first frame
grid()

#Residual plot
difference = Fofx(x,*p) - ydata
frame2=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.2))        
plot(x,difference,'or')
grid()
```

[image: Plot residuals in the bottom by adding another frame using <code>add_axes</code>]

Comment: doesnt work, gives error. Figure not defined

Comment: If 'figure not defined' is the error, then I guess you have to import it from the pylab package like, from pylab import *

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but seeing that this is a top hit for making bottom residual plots, I thought it is useful to modify the code by @jaydeepsb that runs as is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Data
x = np.arange(1,10,0.2)
ynoise = x*np.random.rand(len(x)) 
ydata = x**2 + ynoise

Fofx = lambda x,a,b,c: a*x**2+b*x+c
p, cov = curve_fit(Fofx,x,ydata)

# Upper plot
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
frame1 = fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.8,.6))

plt.plot(x,ydata,'.b') 
plt.plot(x,Fofx(x,*p),'-r') 

frame1.set_xticklabels([]) 
plt.grid()

# Residual plot
difference = Fofx(x,*p) - ydata
frame2 = fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.2))        
plt.plot(x,difference,'or')
plt.grid()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for errorbars like this [pylab_examples example code: errorbar_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html)

You can add an additional subplot and plot the points with the error bars.

Edit: No border between plots:

```
from pylab import *
subplots_adjust(hspace=0.,wspace=0.)
subplot(211)
imshow(rand(100,100), cmap=cm.BuPu_r)
subplot(212)
imshow(rand(100,100), cmap=cm.BuPu_r)
show()
```

Comment: You link does not show how to attach the plots together.

Comment: I thought the errorbars were the problem. I never did that, but after a quick google search I would try this: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code to remove the gap between subplots